# Swing JPanel won't repaint

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, repaint

I have a simple object which extends `JPanel`, when the `update()` method is called on this object it it meant to add some labels to the panel and then repaint. However the labels do not show up after the update method is called, below is the code for update:

```
public void update(){
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        if(cardsHidden){
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                constraints.gridx = i;
                constraints.gridy = 0;
                JLabel card = new JLabel(PlayingCards.cardImages[PlayingCards.CARD_BACK_INDEX]);
                add(card, constraints);
            }
        }
        else{
            Card[] holeCards = player.getHoleCards();
            for(int i = 0; i < holeCards.length; i++){
                constraints.gridx = i;
                constraints.gridy = 0;
                JLabel card = new JLabel(holeCards[i].getImageIcon());
                add(card, constraints); 
            }
        }

        validate();
        repaint();
    }
```

any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT**

solved:

It turns out that the `HoleCardsPanel` wasn't adding to its parent frame properly.  Once that was fixed the adding of new `JLabel`s works fine. I also:

- added the call to the `update()` method to the event dispatch thread using `SwingUtillities.invokeLater`
- had to call `validate()` from the uppermost component (in this case the `JFrame`) as Devon_C_Miller [suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157762/1048186).

Answer (score 25):

It depends on what you want to happen and what layout managers are in use, but the basic rules are:

1. Make sure `update` is called on the EDT. If it's not (`SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`returns false) you will need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to schedule the update on the EDT. For example:

   ```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           update();
       }});
   ```
2. Call `invalidate()`. Most things that change a component will do this for you. So you only need to call this if the following does not work on its own.
3. Call `validate()` on the *highest* affected component. This is probably the muddiest bit of Java's rendering cycle. The call to `invalidate` marks the component and all of its *ancestors* as needing layout. The call to `validate` performs the layout of the component and all of its *descendants*. One works "up" and the other works "down". You need to call `validate` on the highest component in the tree that will be affected by your change.

   Also, calling validate on a top-level component (JWindow, JDialog, JFrame) will not necessarily resize that component. To make that happen, you'll need to call `pack()` or `setSize()`.
4. If your changes alter the size or position of containers, The resized containers will repaint, but they will not erase the space the *used to* occupy. Calling `repaint()` on the parent of the container will cause it to repaint the background, correcting the damage.

Comment: where can I find a good resource that discusses all these rules? The Javadoc isn't explicit about everything you wrote above. Surely there is a better resource...?

Answer (score 17):

Try calling revalidate(); repaint is not what you want.

As per:

> API Docs
>
> Note: If a component has been added to
>   a container that has been displayed,
>   validate must be called on that
>   container to display the new
>   component. If multiple components are
>   being added, you can improve
>   efficiency by calling validate only
>   once, after all the components have
>   been added.

revalidate() is basically a invalidate() followed by a validate().

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859493/remove-swing-component-using-validate-or-revalidate) question.....

Comment: I just tried removing the repaint() statement and changed validate() to revalidate() but no luck :(

Comment: are you calling update from another thread, or the event dispatch thread?

Comment: I am calling update directly from another object running on a standard thread

Comment: Oh, further... call the revalidate on the owning JFrame not the JPanel! Just thought of that.

Comment: JFrame doesnt have a method 'revalidate()'

Comment: for JFrame validate is correct. If that doesn't work try invalidate first.

Answer (score 5):

The call to [`validate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate()) should work, although [`revalidate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) may be sufficient; [`repaint()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) should not be required. You might compare what you're doing to this [example](http://rabbitbrush.frazmtn.com/gridbagtester.html) that does dynamic `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try calling `updateUI()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SetVisible() on the labels ?

Have you tried to add the objets at initialisation without any update ? If they don't show up there, they will never show up.

Comment: Ok. Personnally, I disagree with the downvote. People usually forget simple things like this and this may solve someone else problem.

Comment: Are java components not visible by default on creation?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know the rest of the code. When someone mentions a component not showing up, setvisible comes to my mind. It might not be the solution to the problem for 95 % of people looking for an answer to their own similar problem but for the other 5 % people that will come to this site, to this very question, it will solve it. If I would have said "Did you make sure your screen is turn on ?" I would have agree with a downvote ;)

Comment: Not saying the downvote was worthy, just that he clearly adds the controls in the code above, since he just created them, they MUST be setVisible(true).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `HoleCardsPanel` wansn't adding to its parent frame properly, once that was fixed the adding of new `JLabels` works fine. I added call to the `update()` method to the `event dispatch thread` using `SwingUtillities.invokeLater` I additionaly had to call `validate()` from the uppermost component (in this case the `JFrame`)

Comment: Consider adding these results to your question for future reference.