# Java Swing: repaint() vs invalidate

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint)

Hi all

I'm fighting with my program to make it refresh at the right time.

And not having a lot of success lol

I have 2 questions

Q1: which should I use when my interface has changed: repaint or invalidate?

Q2: when should they be called? I know it sounds stupid but I'm actually having problems because of SwingWorker and other threaded operations.

Comment: I wouldn't say "invalidate" and "revalidate" are the same thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Q1: which should I use when my
>   interface has changed: repaint or
>   invalidate?

If the layout is not up to date because of resizing , font change etc then you should call invalidate. Invalidating a component, invalidates the component and all parents above it are marked as needing to be laid out. Prior to painting, in the validation step if no change is found then the paint step is left out.

If there is some part of component which is being updated (defined by the graphic's clip rectangle, called **"damaged"** region) then you should consider calling repaint. One of the reason a damaged regions may occur is from the overlapping of a part of your component because of some other component or application. 
As per my experience the repaint() is more effective if you call it on the innermost enclosing component (i.e. using `public void repaint(int x, int y, int width, int height)` rather than using public `void repaint()`).

> Q2: when should they be called?

`Invalidate():` marks a component as not valid -- that means, it's layout is or may not be "up to date" anymore: i.e. the component is resized, a border is added, it's font changes, etc. you should never need to call invalidate() by hand, as swing does that for you on pretty much for every property change.

When more than one region within the control needs repainting, Invalidate will cause the entire window to be repainted in a single pass, avoiding flicker caused by redundant repaints. There is no performance penalty for calling Invalidate multiple times before the control is actually repainted.

`Repaint() :` If the component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible.

Also have look at `Update` method.

**NOTE:** Swing processes "repaint" requests in a slightly different way from the AWT, although the final result for the application programmer is essentially the same -- paint() is invoked.

Refer to the link below for an excellent link on how painting is done in AWT and Swing:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Hope this will help.

Comment: When dealing with JComponents, use `revalidate()` instead of `invalidate()`, to ensure the entire component hierarchy is invalidated where appropriate (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859493/remove-swing-component-using-validate-or-revalidate)