# Best way to draw lines java

Tags: java, drawing2d

I have never created a GUI or done anything with drawing in Java and am need of help drawing lines efficiently.  In my app, the user will be provided with 8 buttons, and the idea is when a button is pressed, a line should be drawn on the window corresponding to the time the button is held down.  Currently I am overriding the paintComponent function on a jpanel, and calling the paint() function every 125ms(I only have ~240 pixels wide to draw on, and I would like to keep 30 seconds worth of recording on that 240px), but the hardware it is being run on cannot keep up and it looks terrible/extremely choppy.  Here is the code I am using:

```
jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel() {
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Something cur = manager.getSomething(getCurrentState());
    for(int j=0; j<cur.getNumItems(); j++) {
      Item i1 = cur.getItem(j);
      for(int i = 0; i<i1.getLength(); i++) {
        int start = i1.getStartTime(i);
        int len = Math.max(0, (Math.min(i1.getStopTime(i), pix) - start));
        g.fillRect(start,j*22+5,len,5);
      }
    }
    g.drawLine(pix, 0, pix, 170);
  }
};
```

where:
getItem(int) will return the information for a given button.
getStartTime(int) will return the start time of a given period of time when the button was pressed down.
getStopTime(int) will return the stop time of a given period of time when the button was pressed down.
pix = the current pixel we are at on the panel(so, if we are 15 seconds into the 30 seconds of the timeline, pix would equal 120)

Finally I have a timer which calls jpanel1.paint() every 125ms.

Is there a better way to do this, or does anyone have any other suggestions?  Please provide detailed info/sources as I do not have any real drawing experience.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the code you've tried?

Comment: Can you please refer this tutorial??? I think this is more than enough if you read this much :)

http://beginwithjava.blogspot.in/2008/07/in-most-basic-graphics-app-we-had.html

Comment: "Currently I am overriding the paintComponent function on a jpanel, and calling that function every 125ms" You should not call `paintComponent` method manually

Comment: @vishal_aim I have added the code I am using.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense.  Also, I was mistaken, I am calling the paint function, which I understand calls the paintComponent function.

Comment: even you should not call paint, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

override the paintComponent function of your JPanel

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g)

        g.drawLine(this.x1, this.y1, this.x2, this.y2);
    }
```

Comment: he has already overridden this method (mentioned in question)

Comment: As vishal_aim said, I have already done this, and have updated my post to show the code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

you should **not** call `paint` or `paintComponent` method manually.

For better results you can try `invalidate()` and after that `repaint()` method on your panel after every 125ms

you may also be interested in [repaint and invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396583/java-swing-repaint-vs-invalidate)