# Repaint many elements with one button click in GUI app

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

Hello, I've been working on a GUI application that should resize dynamically and change background color multiple times after clicking a button. My first shot was to make a `for` loop inside an `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method but it doesn't work properly. Strangely enough, the app changes properly if the listener is removed and the commented code from `main` function is used. Why is that?

This code is actually a simple example of a problem which I've came across making a slightly more complex app. Could You kindly add a line or two if the solution varies if my window consists of many `JPanels` and I decide to repeatedly change properties of some other elements with one button click?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class TempWindow {

    public static void main(String [] args ) {
        Frame f = new Frame();

//      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
//          if(i == 0) {
//          f.getMyPanel().setBackground(Color.red);
//          }
//          if (i == 1) {
//          f.setSize(500, 400);
//          f.getMyPanel().setBackground(Color.yellow);
//          }
//          if( i == 2) {
//              f.setSize(100, 200);
//              f.getMyPanel().setBackground(Color.green);
//          }
//          
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(500);
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
//          f.repaint();
//      }

    }

}

class Frame extends JFrame {

    MyPanel panel;
    JButton but1;

    public Frame() {

        this.setSize(400, 300);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        but1 = new JButton("Start");
        this.getContentPane().add(but1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panel = new MyPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        but1.addActionListener(new DanceActionListener(this));

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MyPanel getMyPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel text;

    public MyPanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        text  = new JLabel(" xxx ");
        text.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 40));
        this.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        text.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        text.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
}

class DanceActionListener implements ActionListener {

    MyPanel panel;
    Frame f;

    public DanceActionListener(Frame f) {
        this.f = f;
        this.panel = f.getMyPanel();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.red);
                panel.repaint();
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                f.setSize(500, 400);
            }
            if( i == 2) {
                f.setSize(100, 200);
                panel.setBackground(Color.green);
            }

            f.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);` Whatever you are trying to achieve there, this is the wrong way to go about it.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: The reason it works in the `main` is because the UI has been moved to another thread (the EDT), but you should never modify the UI from outside of the context of the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer I reckon those 2 comments together are the makings of an answer..

Comment: BTW - `Frame f = new Frame();` should be `JFrame f = new JFrame();` for a Swing app.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396583/java-swing-repaint-vs-invalidate